# Using boost::optional arguments as parameters in template functions

Tags: c++, boost, option-type, optional-parameters

I have a function that reads parameters of various types from a file, and I'd like the ability to supply default parameters. Using a simple default function argument isn't a good solution because it's impossible to differentiate in the function whether the argument was specified or if the default was used. So I thought I'd use `boost::optional`. I have a function that looks something like

```
template <typename T>
void func(T& out, boost::optional<T> def_val) {
 // do stuff
}
```

but this fails at type deduction, e.g.

```
double x;
func(x, 3.0); // error: could not match optional against double
func(x, boost::optional<double>(3.0)); // ok but way too verbose
func<double>(x,3.0); // ok and better but still not ideal
```

which surprises me, I thought the first `out` parameter would be enough for the compiler to deduce `T = double` and parse the second argument correctly. Is there any way to do this nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates have exact matching for type deduction. In your example `int` and `double` are two possibilities for `T`, so the compiler gives you an error. In other parts of the language, the compiler will attempt to find a common type (for `int` and `double`, this is `double`), but not for template type deduction.

You can prevent the second argument from participating in type deduction with a simple wrapper, where it's impossible in general for the compiler to deduce the type from it:

```
template<typename T>
struct id {typedef T type;};

template <typename T>
void func(T& out, boost::optional<typename id<T>::type> def_val) {
 // do stuff
}
```

You can see this compile and deduce `double` for `T` [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a7d9de9dcf4984d). Note that it doesn't link simply because I removed the definition of `func` so that the example displays the deduced type.